# ID user decrement error raised in the console but has no actual effect on Blender. What's the cause of that?

Tags: python, scripting, error, properties, command-line

[image: screenshot]

By displaying the property I am getting this error by editing the property or simple scrolling around in the node editor. So maybe something with the layout or UI?

> ERROR (bke.lib_id): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v340\blender.git\source\blender\blenkernel\intern\lib_id.c:328 id_us_min: ID user decrement error: OBarc.003 (from '[Main]'): 0 <= 0

But the weird part is that this error doesn't seem to affect the actual functioning of Blender in any way, the rest of the code I've written seems to work as intended, and Blender doesn't crash or exhibit any other strange behaviour. If the system console didn't raise this error, I wouldn't even know anything's amiss. I can't figure out any other way to delete these screens that works as intended, so I'm considering just entirely ignoring this error and moving on, but I know that's not best practice. Why is this error being raised and how can I change my code to avoid this? Thank you!